# Stripping image metadata

Tags: apt, package-management

A while back, on an old installation, I had installed a package that allowed me to view and delete metadata from images. I'm fairly certain the syntax was as follows

To display the metadata in an image

```
mat -d <name of image>
```

To clear metadata from an image

```
mat -c <name of image>
```

I have reinstalled my computer, but I can't seem to remember what the package name is. I'm aware that there are alternatives (exiftool or something), but it's really bothering me that I can't remember what it was called. If anyone knows what package I'm talking about, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for package `mat` (Metadata Anonymisation Toolkit).

Install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install mat
```

Also note that, `mat -c` will not clear metadata, it will check if the file in consideration is free of harmful metadatas. Check `man mat` for details.

`mat` is available on the `universe` repository. If `universe` repository is not enabled already, you need to [enable it first](https://askubuntu.com/q/148638/216503).